# How to determine number of independent variables in regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics

I have heard that having more than one independent variable is useful when predicting human behaviour since it can be influenced by a combination of several factors!

Forgetting about the limitations like the number of observations, is there any way to decide how many independent variables to include in a model? I mean, suppose one has 20 observations and is doing a multiple regression with 2 independent variables. Can we criticize him just because he has 2 predictors?

Comment: (1) first you say you're forgetting the limitations of number of observations then you mention them..? EDV usually plays a part in model building (2) I think the rest is less a statistical issue than knowledge domain issue.

Comment: @charles +1 for (2). Domain knowledge should always come first. One should also consider the use case of the model; e.g. descriptive vs predictive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with including too many independent terms is that you risk over-fitting your data. There is no magic number or threshold, but as a rule of thumb the less data you have the greater this risk becomes.

You can, however evaluate your fit by doing something like cross-validation. This works by training on some portion of your data, and then evaluating the goodness of fit on some held out portion. A simple starting point is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29).

Comment: Cross-validation is hardly a solution for n = 20.

Answer (score 1):

You write

> I have heard that having more than one independent variable is useful
> when predicting human behaviour since it can be influenced by a
> combination of several factors!

That is correct. It's hard to think of any human behavior that is related to only one variable

> Forgetting about the limitations like the number of observations,

That's not a good idea, and later in your question you give a small sample size.

> is there any way to decide how many independent variables to include
> in a model?

Lots of ways, both statistical and substantive. E.g. statistically, you can look at increase in $R^2$ or adjusted $R^2$ or likelihood ratio tests, or AIC or BIC.  Substantively, you can read the literature and talk with experts.

> I mean, suppose one has 20 observations and is doing a multiple
> regression with 2 independent variables. Can we criticize him just
> because he has 2 predictors?

2 predictors with N = 20 is probably OK, but N = 20 is a very small sample.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only 2 variables, you can probably use judgement or even trial and error to see what gives you the best generalized results. However, things become much more complicated when you have hundreds or thousands of variables.

I that case, you often do what analysis you can for variable dependency, but you rely on other techniques for dealing with getting rid of redundant dimensions or preventing over fitting. Techniques such as regularization and dimension reduction (using Principle Component Analysis, etc) become necessary.

At a certain level, making these judgement and using these tools requires experience and is as much craft (I won't go so far as to say art) as science.